# Jaspersoft Studio: How to send a array parameter (table of numbers) to an pl/sql function?

Tags: collections, plsql, jasper-reports, ireport

I want to send a list of numbers to a pl/sql function. The typedef of the argument is: `TYPE colNumbers IS TABLE OF NUMBER(5,0)`. In a normal SQL query i call my function with

```
select (Test.argLoN(colNumbers(1,2,3,4,5,6))) as "asd" from dual
```

This part works fine.

I read that JR engine call the toString() method of the parameters. So in ireport 5.5.1 (the eclipse plugin version) I created a parameter with type String and give him the "default expression" "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10". In the query dialog I call the statement:

```
select (Test.argLoN(colNumbers($P{val})) as "asd" 
from dual
```

If I run the report I get this error msg:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : Test

If i understand this right.

```
select (Test.argLoN(colNumbers($P{val})) as "asd" from dual"
```

with val = "1,2,3,4,5" should create

```
select (Test.argLoN(colNumbers(1,2,3,4,5))) as "asd" from dual
```

Or did I misunderstand it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the parameter literal in iReport.

```
$P!{Values}
```

Instead of

```
$P{Values}
```

Using $P!{} will try not to escape, or "parameterize' the input.   How may values you can appreciably use in statement like that will depend on your datasource.

Comment: This: "select (Test.argLoN(colNumbers($P!{clobval}))) as "asd" from dual" still doesn't work. :/

Comment: Do you have a way to trace the generated SQL in Postgres?